# Extract APP Links (URI) from a third party app

Tags: android, android-studio, uri, applinks

I am developing an Android App (A) that can launch a third part app (B) and go to a specific page of the app.
For example, In my app A, I have a button which when pressed must open another application and start an activity.

I understood this can be done using URI. How can I extract URI's of third party apps ?

Comment: By "extract URI" do you mean "to find out which URI would be opened by which third-party app"?

Comment: "I understood this can be done using URI" -- not usually.

Comment: @commonsWare thanks, how else can we do it? Can we try automation using Selenium

Comment: If you are writing tests, use [Ui Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator). Or, if you are writing tests, Selenium might support this as well -- I have not used it. However, your question is not about writing tests, but writing an app. Apps in general cannot automate other apps, for obvious security reasons.